# Javascript Object disable auto update Object parent

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
var obj_a = {"A":1231,"B":34534,...};
var obj_b = obj_a;
for(var id in obj_b){
  //do something
  delete obj_b[id];
}
console.log(obj_b); // {}
console.log(obj_a); // {}
```

I don't want `obj_a` is `{}`

How I can fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would help you.
We create `obj_b` by copy obj_a value.

```
var obj_b = Object.assign({},obj_a);
```

For more information : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to do a deep copy `obj_a` and assign it to `obj_b` like:

```
var obj_b = Object.assign({}, obj_a)
```

`obj_a` is a reference to the object you created and hence the line `obj_b = obj_a` is making a copy to the reference, not it's value. Therefore when you mutate the values of `obj_b` in the for-loop, you are mutating the values to the reference `obj_a` holds as well.

Edit: just had a look at the[benchmarks](http://jsben.ch/bWfk9) and noticed that `Object.assign` is now faster than `JSON.stringify`